# Stata portable code with mkdir

Tags: if-statement, stata, mkdir

So, I'm trying to write a line of that will check if there is a directory present, and only try and create a directory if that is false. Found this on Statalist:

```
local name test_directory
cd C:\
capture confirm file "./`name'/nul" // check if `name' subdir exists
if _rc { // _rc will be >0 if it doesn't exist
    !md "`name'"
    }

// my do file
save "C:/`name'/current_data.dta"  // optionally add -,replace-
```

Looks pretty solid overall for my application, but I'm struggling with converting it to Mac compatible syntax.

```
local name test_directory
cd ~/
capture confirm file "./`name'/*" 
// check if `name' subdir exists
if _rc { 
    mkdir "`name'"
    }
```

Any advice on how to do this right?

Comment: What exactly happens when you execute the second piece of code? That code works for me in a Linux environment, which (as I understand) uses terminal commands nearly identical to mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try relying on the return code of the `cd` command. This is the approach taken by `confirmdir` (from SSC):

```
local somedir /home/roberto/Desktop/test

quietly capture cd `"`somedir'"'
if (_rc) display as text "return code `=_rc'; do something, like mkdir"
else display as text "could change dir; the dir exists"
```

This will signal if

> cd was unable to change to the directory you typed because either it
>   does not exist, it is protected, or it is not a directory

Source: `search r(170)`.

If you plan on issuing several commands after the conditionals, then you need the `if {...} else {...}` syntax. See `help ifcmd`.

If you don't want to end up in a different directory, you can save the current one at the beginning

```
local cwd `"`c(pwd)'"'
```

and switch back to it when your done:

```
quietly cd `"`cwd'"'
```

It should work on both MS Windows and Unix-type OS. (But I can't test on MS Windows.)

Comment: Thanks! That was a perfect answer that made me think about the question appropriately, and didn't give me so much information I could copy paste and refit a few aspects. Got it to work perfectly, and used a similar command to address a number of other issues in my code.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use the shell for things like this:

```
local name test_directory
cd ~
!if test -d `name'; then echo "`name' Already Exists"; else mkdir `name'; fi
```

I don't really understand why your second code fails.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the asterisk at the end of the capture statement: if test_directory exists but is empty, nothing will match and _rc will be nonzero. Maybe you meant the asterisk to be a "."?

But the slash before that character is also a problem: if a plain file exists named test_directory, the confirm will fail because "test_directory/." does not exist but mkdir will also fail because of the name conflict.

The following works for me, Stata 13.1 on OS X 10.10, with a little extra output for debugging to confirm what path I've taken.

```
local name test_directory
cd "~/Research/Stata sandbox"
capture confirm file "./`name'" 
// check if `name' subdir exists
if _rc { 
    mkdir "`name'"
    display "`name' created"
    }
else {
    display "`name' already exists"
    }
```

Comment: It runs when I do it in the main window, but when I try and run it in the do-file, it cuts out when trying to make the directory, stating that it already exists.

Comment: I run it from the do-file editor successfully. But that's OK, Roberto's solution is better: I upvoted it myself.

Comment: Yep. It was the way to go. But thank you for taking the time to help me out!

Answer (score 1):

The following works on all platforms

```
local dir_to_use "whatever_dir_name"
capture mkdir "`dir_to_use'"
```

Nothing bad will happen if the directory already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Some may find this simple solution for a do-file handy:

```
local name test_directory

capture mkdir "C:/`name'/"

save "C:/`name'/current_data.dta"
```

This will make a folder with the name test_directory if this folder is not already present. The code also runs without error if the folder already existed.